# Trying to stop/continue ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data:{ },
        url:'pulldata.php',
        timeout:3000,
        success:function (data) {

            $('#thediv').html(data.html);

            $(".expandhide").click(function () { // THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK
                $(this).parents().next(".infopanel").toggle(500);
            });


            window.setTimeout(update, 3000);
        },
        error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            window.setTimeout(update, 60000);
        }
    });
```

The .expandhide function expands/hides an element. I need ajax to stop making further calls when the user has clicked on .expandhide (expand) and resume ajax calls when the user has clicked on it again (to hide it). Pretty much exactly how I toggle .infopanel, except with ajax to stop/continue calls. Can this be done?

Comment: How about adding a flag variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the interval to a variable and clear it when you hide it:

```
var timeout = null;
var expanded = false;
var ajax = null;
$(".expandhide").click(function() {
    expanded = !expanded; //Reverse it
    if (expanded) {
        update(); //Call update again but right away
    } else {
        //Abort the ongoing ajax call (if any)
        if (ajax !== null) ajax.abort(); 

        //Clear the timeout
        if (timeout !== null) clearTimeout(timeout); 
    }
});

//Set the global "ajax" variable to our request - don't use "var" here
ajax = $.ajax(
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        // Do NOT use "var" here, as we're referencing the global variable
        timeout = setTimeout(update, 3000);  
    }
    ...
);
```

Alternatively, as a quick fix, just add a `beforeSend` anonymous function that cancels sending it if your `.infopanel` isn't visible:

```
$.ajax(
    ...
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        if ($(".infopanel").is(":hidden")) {
            return false; //Don't send the request
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I prefer your second solution. I just had to add setTimeout so it would keep checking if it's hidden or not. Thanks again.